# ROR beginner, why is one version of my query working but not the other

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following works fine:

```
def self.already_joined?(days_event,user)
    already_joined=DaysEventsUser.where(:user_id=>user, :days_events_id=>days_event)
    if !already_joined.empty?
        return true
    end
end
```

but the following does not:

```
def self.already_joined?(days_event,user)
already_joined=DaysEventsUser.where("user_id=>? AND days_events_id=>?",user,days_event)
if !already_joined.empty?
    return true
end
end
```

Its my understanding that the second one is safer, and the query seems to work fine on its own but as soon as I try to measure if its returned a value I get the error:

Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=>37 AND days_events_id=>'20')' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `days_events_users`  WHERE (user_id=>37 AND days_events_id=>'20')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
already_joined=DaysEventsUser.where("user_id= ? AND days_events_id= ?",user,days_event)
```